# create multiple 'view in app' links using Branch.io in index view

Tags: ios, branch.io

I'd like to create an index view which shows a list of items followed by a 'view in app' button to download data directly into the app.

**Solution 1. [Not a sulution]** I think [deepviewcta](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Smart-App-Banner-Deep-Linking-Web-SDK/blob/master/Reference.md#deepviewcta) call is appropriated to use in a single product page. It doesn't look like suitable in my case, because it has to call [deepview](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Smart-App-Banner-Deep-Linking-Web-SDK/blob/master/Reference.md#deepviewdata-options-callback) before calling [deepviewcta](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Smart-App-Banner-Deep-Linking-Web-SDK/blob/master/Reference.md#deepviewcta).

**Solution 2.** I'm trying to construct the URL directly using ['dynamic' deeplink](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Deferred-Deep-Linking-Public-API#structuring-a-dynamic-deeplink). The documentation says any additional query param appended will shows up in the initSession callback, but it doesn't work for me.

the construct link looks like this:

```
https://bnc.lt/a/key_test_kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk?has_app=yes&channel=character&my_list_id=0c56c4bc-fac9-412a-be19-c0feefe30d29
```

what I got in the callback only has following data

```
"+clicked_branch_link" = 0;
"+is_first_session" = 0;
```

in the callback, other params are just missing, I got:

```
url NSURL * @"my-app://open?link_click_id=197576253652400385"   0x00007fad90d47450
```

**Any Other Solutions?**

Comment: Hi Zitao -- I just sent you an email. We don't append params to the NSURL, but rather return them in-app. I sent a series of questions that will help us determine where the issue lies. Hoping to hear from you soon.

Comment: Glad we isolated the issue. For anyone else wondering, be sure to use getTestInstance inside your iOS app if you're using a link from your test app.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using live key in ios App while using test key in server end. So solution 2 works now.

Also for anyone want to do the same thing. For regular Branch Links, it is not possible to stay on the same page as the Branch link was clicked from. they suggest adding a $after_click_url to the Link's data. This key will tell the system to route to a particular web address after the Branch Link has been clicked.

Thanks for branch.io's support, they responded very quickly.